# Comparing 2 arrays using numpy and allocating values to a third array

Tags: python, numpy

I have

```
A = numpy.array([[ 0.52241976,  0.50960677,  0.34597965]])
B = numpy.array([[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]])
```

I am looking for a C that does

```
if (A > B):
C[i] = 1

Expected C: [[ 1, 1, 0]]
```

How do I do that?

Edit: I have started python today. So I am early beginner in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is made for this purpose

```
C = numpy.where(A > B, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you could just do

```
(A > B).astype(int)
```

As booleans convert to `int` as `0` and `1`